# Django - How to implement authentication service in microservices architecture

Tags: django, jwt, microservices

Basically, I have several independent services. I want to build a service for authentication. When client get a token from authentication service. Client use it for further request to others services. Client need to attach that token in header of request. The services receiving token need to verify the token by sending it to authentication server. So all requests that clients make to protected routes need to be verified by authentication service. The thing is I do not know the best place to put the code that automatically sends token to authentication service and receive the result. 
Here is what i tried so far:
I implemented a middleware like that:

```
class VerifyTokenMiddleware(object):

def process_request(self, request):
    if not request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'):
        return HttpResponse(status=404)
    auth_header = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
    token = auth_header[4:]
    response = requests.post(AUTH_URL, {"token": token})
    if response.status_code == 400:
        return HttpResponse(status=403)
    return None
```

However, the problem of my solution is every requests to services(not auth service) have to pass through that middleware. Therefore, client cannot access unprotected routes like before. 
Any help is extremely appreciated. :D

I used django restframework jwt https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt.

Comment: But why do the microservices (MS) need to validate the token? The JWT token contains all the data it needs to be validated inplace: each MS can verify the signature and extract the embeded data (like userId)

Comment: FYI http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#verify-token

Comment: So, you also need to validate the token validity. However, your solution is not very resilient. What happens if the central authentication MS goes down ?

Answer (score -4):

It have many way to desiged microservice, you can write file restfull method like

```
class RestFulClient:
   @classmethod
   def get(cls, url, loggers, headers):
       return is_success, status_code, data

   @classmethod
   def post(cls, url, headers, loggers, params={}):
       return is_success, status_code, status_message, data

   @classmethod
   def put(cls, url, headers, loggers, params={}):
       return is_success, status_code, status_message, data

   @classmethod
   def delete(cls, url, headers, loggers, params={}):
       return is_success, status_code, status_message
```

Any question?

Comment: It seems like you did not get my question. I want to implement a Authentication service using json web token https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt